# Creating permutations from columns in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, permutation

Hi I have a dataframe as follows:

[image]

And would like to create a dataframe with 2 columns:

Writer1 Writer2

that lists all the permutations of writers of a song ex: for the song 03 Bonnie & Clyde the writers: Prince, Tupac Shakur, Jay-Z, Tyrone Wrice and Kanye West were involved. My dataframe therefore should look like:

```
Writer1 Writer2

Prince  Tupac Shakur

Prince  Jay-Z

Prince  Tyrone Wrice

Prince  Kanye West

Tupac S Jay-Z

Tupac S Tyrone Wrice

Tupac S Kanye West

Jay-Z   Tyrone Wrice

Jay-Z   Kanye West

Tyrone  Kanye West
```

Any idea how I can go about it pls?

Comment: Please enter the correct description for the linked image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using `itertools.combinations`:

```py
import itertools
import pandas as pd

def get_combinations(df, song_name):
    """
    Get a dataframe of all two-writer combinations for a given song.

    :param df: dataframe containing all artists, songs and writers
    :param song_name: name of song 
    :returns: dataframe with cols 'Writer1', 'Writer2' of all two writer combinations for the given song
    """
    song_frame = df[df['Song'] == song_name]
    combinations_df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(song_frame['Writer'].unique(), 2)), 
                                   columns=['Writer1', 'Writer2'])
    return combinations_df

combinations_df = get_combinations(df, '03 Bonnie & Clyde')
```

Note that this assumes your data is in the form of a Pandas dataframe. You can easily read in from a text file or csv, or create one like the following to test:

```py
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Artist':np.repeat('Jay-Z',5).tolist() + ['David Bowie'] * 2 + ['List of the X Factor finalists'] * 2,
                   'Song':np.repeat('03 Bonnie & Clyde',5).tolist() + ['Heroes'] * 4,
                   'Writer':['Prince', 'Tupac Shakur',
                             'Jaz-Z', 'Tyrone Wrice',
                             'Kanye West'] + ['David Bowie', 'Brian Eno'] * 2})
```

If you want to efficiently apply this over your whole dataframe, consider:

```py
def combinations_per_group(group):
    """Return combinations of writers after grouping by song."""     
    group_combs = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(group['Writer'].unique(),2)),
                               columns=['Writer1', 'Writer2'])
combinations_df = df.groupby(['Song']).apply(combinations_per_group)\
                    .reset_index()\
                    .drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

This returns a dataframe with the song as the index and the desired columns giving all combinations of writers per song.

Comment: what is that level_1 doing pls?

Comment: In the `groupby` operation, for each group, a new dataframe is created with all the combinations of writers. If there are 10 combinations, for example, the new dataframe will have index `[0,...,9]`. After the function is applied across the whole dataframe, the final output has a multi-index consisting of both the song names and the per-group integer indexes. `drop('level_1', axis=1)` just drops the per-group integer indexes, because they aren't important to us and what we really care about is the song names.